# Asp.net 5 Web template missing Bower files

Tags: gulp, asp.net-core

ASP.NET 5 has a folder named Dependencies->Bower which the default Web template contains things like bootstrap, hammer.js, and jquery.  These dependencies are copied to a lib folder according to gulpfile.js.

```
var paths = {
  bower: "./bower_components/",
  lib: "./" + project.webroot + "/lib/"
};
```

For some reason my site is missing all the styling and client behavior (carousel) that used to work fine, and the lib files appear to always be blank documents now.  Does the gulpfile.js run during a VS build?  Is there something else I need to do to re-copy these files to lib?

[image: Empty files]

[image: Missing dependencies]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the Task Runner Explorer in Visual Studio, right click on the copy task, and click run.

I'm not sure how the files got removed or why this was necessary, but it does fix the problem.

[image]